How to fix nuxt redirect to homepage on hard refresh and direct access to any page?
Steps to reproduce
Navigation via links work perfectly, but if you tried to access any page directly or refresh any page it will redirect you to home page.
What is expected ?
Access any page directly or refresh any page should not redirect to homepage
What is actually happening?
Access any page directly or refresh any page redirect you to home page.
Additional comments?
When the Content Security Policy (nuxt-security) is disabled, the problem is solved (I'm not sure), but this time settings such as css are corrupted.
When I follow the steps below, the website works properly for a while.
right click -> inspect -> application -> storage -> Clear site (including third-party cookies)
Here is the website config nuxt.config.ts
  typescript: {
    includeWorkspace: true
  },
  
  experimental:  {
    asyncContext: true
  },

  app: {
    head: {
      meta: [
        { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"},
        { name: "format-detection", content: "telephone=yes" },
        { name: "theme-color", content: "#ffffff " },
        { name: "msapplication-TileColor", content: "#da532c" },
        { property: "og:site:name", content: "Example" },
        { name: "og:type", property: "og:type", content: "website" },
        { property: "og:title", content: "Example" },
        { property: "og:url", content: process.env.BASE_URL },
        { property: "og:image", content: "/img/fl.webp" },
        { property: "og:image:secure_url", content: "/img/fl.webp" },
        { name: "twitter:url", content: process.env.BASE_URL },
        { name: "twitter:image", content: "/img/fl.webp" },
        { name: "twitter:image:alt", content: "Example" },
        { name: "twitter:card", content: "summary" },
        { name: "twitter:title", content: "Example" },
        { "http-equiv": "content-type", content: "text/html", charset: "utf-8" },
        { "http-equiv": "content-language", content: "tr" }, 
        { name: "robots", content: "index, follow" }, 
        { name: "revisit-after", content: "7 days" }
      ],
      link: [
        { rel: "shortcut icon", type: "image/vnd.microsoft.icon", href: "/img/pwa/favicon.ico" },
        { rel: "canonical", href: process.env.BASE_URL },
        { rel: "apple-touch-icon", sizes: "180x180", href: "/img/pwa/apple-touch-icon.png" },
        { rel: "icon", type: "image/png", sizes: "16x16", href: "/img/pwa/favicon-16x16.png" },
        { rel: "icon", type: "image/png", sizes: "32x32", href: "/img/pwa/favicon-32x32.png" },
        { rel: "mask-icon", href: "/img/pwa/safari-pinned-tab.svg", color: "#5bbad5" },
        { rel: "preconnect", href: "https://www.google-analytics.com" }
      ],
      script: [ { src: process.env.gtm, async: true }, { src: process.env.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA, defer: true } ],
      noscript: [{ children: "JavaScript is required." }]
    }
  },

 modules: [
    ["@pinia/nuxt", {storesDirs: ["./store/**"]}],
    "@vite-pwa/nuxt",
    ["nuxt-purgecss", { enabled: true, safelist: { deep: [/svg.*/, /fa.*/, /dark.*/, /light.*/] }, fontFace: true, variables: true, keyframes: true, rejected: true }],
    "@nuxtjs/color-mode",
    "nuxt-security",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n",
    ["vue-recaptcha/nuxt", { enterprise: true }]
  ],

  plugins: [ { src: "@/plugins/font-awesome.ts" }, { src: "@/plugins/useBootstrap.client.ts", mode: "client" }],

  css: [
    "@/assets/scss/app.scss",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css",
    "/node_modules/flag-icons/css/flag-icons.min.css",
    "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],

  router: {options: { linkActiveClass: "active" }},
  routeRules: { "/": { prerender: true }, "/assets/**/*": { headers: { "cache-control": "public,max-age=31536000 ,s-maxage=31536000" }, cache: { maxAge: 31536000 } } },

  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      cssnano: {
        preset: "default"
      }
    }
  },

  build: {
    transpile: ["@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core", "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons", "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons", "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons", "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome"],
    analyze: { enabled: true }
  },

  nitro: {
    compressPublicAssets: true,
    minify: true,
    publicAssets: [{ baseURL: "css", dir: "public/css", maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 }, { dir: "public/img", maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 }, { baseURL: "js", dir: "public/js", maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 }, { baseURL: "video", dir: "public/video", maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 }],
    analyze: {
      emitFile: true,
      filename: "analysis.html",
      title: "Analysis",
      gzipSize: true,
      brotliSize: true,
      sourcemap: true
    }
  },

  vite: {
    css: { preprocessorOptions: { scss: { additionalData: "@use '@/assets/scss/globalVariables.scss' as *;" } } },
    server: {
      cors: {
        methods: "GET, POST, DELETE",
        origin: "*",
        allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"]
      }
    },
    preview: { cors: { methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"] } }
  },
  security: {
    enabled: true,
    corsHandler: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"],
      credentials: false
    },
    headers: {
      xFrameOptions: "DENY",
      xXSSProtection: "1; mod=block",
      xPermittedCrossDomainPolicies: "none",
      strictTransportSecurity: {
        maxAge: 15552000,
        includeSubdomains: true,
        preload: true
      },
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        "base-uri": ["'none'"],
        "default-src": ["'self'"],
        "connect-src": ["'self'", "https://example.com"],
        "font-src": ["'self'"],
        "form-action": ["'self'"],
        "frame-ancestors": ["'none'"],
        "frame-src": ["'self'", "https://www.google.com"],
        "img-src": ["'self'", "data:"],
        "manifest-src": ["'self'"],
        "media-src": ["'self'"],
        "object-src": ["'none'"],
        "script-src": ["'self'", 'https:', "'unsafe-inline'", "'strict-dynamic'", "'nonce-{{nonce}}'"],
        "script-src-attr": ["'none'"],
        "script-src-elem": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "https://www.google.com", "https://www.gstatic.com", "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js"],
        "style-src": ["self", "'nonce-{{nonce}}'", "'strict-dynamic'", "https://example.com/"],
        "style-src-attr": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        "style-src-elem": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
        "worker-src": ["'self'"],
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": true
      },
      originAgentCluster: "?1",
      xContentTypeOptions: "nosniff",
      referrerPolicy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
      xDownloadOptions: "noopen"
    },
    requestSizeLimiter: {
      maxRequestSizeInBytes: 2000000,
      maxUploadFileRequestInBytes: 8000000,
      throwError: true
    },
    rateLimiter: {
      tokensPerInterval: 150,
      interval: "hour",
      headers: true,
      throwError: true
    },
    allowedMethodsRestricter: {
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"],
      throwError: true
    },
    xssValidator: {
      stripIgnoreTag: true,
      stripIgnoreTagBody: true,
      throwError: true,
      css: true,
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"]
    },
    nonce: true,
    sri: true,
    ssr: true
  },

  pwa: {
    useCredentials: true,
    registerType: "autoUpdate",
    includeAssets: ['apple-touch-icon.png', 'android-chrome-192x192.png', 'android-chrome-512x512.png', 'favicon.ico', 'favicon-16x16.png', 'favicon-32x32.png', 'mstile-150x150.png', 'safari-pinned-tab.svg'],
    manifest: {
      name: "Example",
      short_name: "Example",
      description: "Example",
      theme_color: "#110F0F",
      background_color: "#110F0F",
      start_url: process.env.BASE_URL,
      id: process.env.BASE_URL,
      scope: process.env.BASE_URL,
      orientation: "any",
      icons: [
        {
          src: "/img/pwa/android-chrome-192x192.png",
          type: "image/png",
          sizes: "192x192"
        },
        {
          src: "/img/pwa/android-chrome-512x512.png",
          type: "image/png",
          sizes: "512x512"
        },
        {
          src: "/img/pwa/android-chrome-512x512.png",
          type: "image/png",
          sizes: "512x512",
          purpose: "maskable"
        }
      ],
      display_override: ["fullscreen", "minimal-ui", "standalone"],
      shortcuts: [
        {
          name: "Home Page",
          url: "/",
          description: "Home Page",
          icons: [
            {
              src: "/img/pwa/android-chrome-96x96.png",
              sizes: "96x96",
              type: "image/png",
              purpose: "any"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Sectors",
          url: "/sectors/list",
          description: "Sectors Page",
          icons: [
            {
              src: "/img/pwa/android-chrome-96x96.png",
              sizes: "96x96",
              type: "image/png",
              purpose: "any"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "About",
          url: "/about",
          description: "About Page",
          icons: [
            {
              src: "/img/pwa/android-chrome-96x96.png",
              sizes: "96x96",
              type: "image/png",
              purpose: "any"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Contact",
          url: "/contact",
          description: "Contact Page",
          icons: [
            {
              src: "/img/pwa/android-chrome-96x96.png",
              sizes: "96x96",
              type: "image/png",
              purpose: "any"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Login",
          url: "/login",
          description: "Login Page",
          icons: [
            {
              src: "/img/pwa/android-chrome-96x96.png",
              sizes: "96x96",
              type: "image/png",
              purpose: "any"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Register",
          url: "/register",
          description: "Register Page",
          icons: [
            {
              src: "/img/pwa/android-chrome-96x96.png",
              sizes: "96x96",
              type: "image/png",
              purpose: "any"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Profile",
          url: "/profile",
          description: "Profile Page",
          icons: [
            {
              src: "/img/pwa/android-chrome-96x96.png",
              sizes: "96x96",
              type: "image/png",
              purpose: "any"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      protocol_handlers: [
        { protocol: "mailto", url: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/newEmail?to=%s` }
      ]
    },
    workbox: {
      globPatterns: ["**/*.{js,css,html,png,webp,ico,mp4,svg}"],
      navigateFallback: "/",
      offlineGoogleAnalytics: true,
      clientsClaim: true,
      cleanupOutdatedCaches: true
    },
    injectManifest: {
        globPatterns: ["**/*.{js,css,html,png,webp,ico,mp4,svg}"]
    }
  },

  i18n: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
    experimental: { autoImportTranslationFunctions: true },
    langDir: "locales/",
    strategy: "no_prefix",
    skipSettingLocaleOnNavigate: true,
    defaultLocale: "tr",
    detectBrowserLanguage: {
      useCookie: true,
      fallbackLocale: "tr",
      alwaysRedirect: true,
      cookieSecure: true,
      redirectOn: "root",
      cookieKey: "lng"
    },
    locales: [
      { code: "tr", iso: "tr-TR", name: "Türkçe", file: "tr.json", flag: "fi fi-tr" },
      { code: "en", iso: "en-US", name: "English", file: "en.json", flag: "fi fi-gb" }
    ]
  }



